# Can we use soft assert in Junit as like TestNG...?

Tags: cucumber-junit

**Can we use soft assert in Junit as like TestNG:**

I dont want to fail my Test Case if Assert Condition fail

Any way to solve this use case

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```java
import org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions;
```

Code:

```java
SoftAssertions softAssertions = new SoftAssertions();
softAssertions.assertThat(searchCriteriaPage.count()).isEqualTo(searchCriteria.getCount());
softAssertions.assertAll();
```

Maven Dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -5):

**Yes we can do:**

```
softAssertions = new SoftAssertions();
```